# Change brightness/exposure/contrast of AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am using AVCaptureSession to output a still image, which I will later use to get the dominant color out of and display these as a color scheme.

The problem is that the video preview is very desaturated (with a greenish hue) and also with low contrast. I was wondering if there is a way to change the brightness, contrast, etc. using AVFoundation or if I would need to use a framework?